# Possible to replace CPU fans?

Tags: cpu, fan, desktop-computer

I have an Intel CPU that is about 5 years old and the integrated fan is whining.

Is it possible to replace just the fan, or will that be problematic?

The numbers on the fan are:

```
E21984
DTCAAU01
DP827G30
```

The fan has an integrated plastic cage that attaches to the motherboard via 4 plastic posts.

Comment: The fan housing itself is often just clipped onto the lower assembly - like this. https://goo.gl/images/aVbKFT Replacements are easy to find & cheap. Your first number comes up as this shallower assembly, still clip-on - https://www.amazon.co.uk/Intel-Copper-E21984-001-E21984-001-CPU-Cooler-Socket/dp/B01I5AIN2S

Comment: If they are so easy to find then why not tell us where to get it? Your Amazon listing says it's no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that for older fans you are unlikely to find it in normal retail channels like Amazon, but there is a market in such equipment in places like eBay where older computer equipment is sold.

So, in short, you can find fan/heatsink replacements, but you have to go to a "used/obsolete" sales source.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely. Photos taken to a local computer store will confirm for sure and they will be able to sell you something.

The clips require pinching to allow the fan to lift up (if I'm thinking of the right thing). This can be difficult, and I'm not sure if there's a tool available for it (any time I've done it has been disassembly and destruction hasn't been a concern).

The most important numbers are the voltage (probably either 5V or 12V) and the diameter of the fan (so that it fits on the existing mounts)

Edit: I've looked at the specific CPU fan you quote, and it's definitely a non-standard shape. You may have more difficulty replacing just the fan, and may require a new heatsink/fan combo. Note this will be a more intrusive change and will require thermal paste as well.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR available at the end.

---

You can't replace the fan without replacing the entire plastic  housing on most of the stock Intel coolers. The fan assembly is built right into that plastic frame, which you can see by looking into the gap where the wires connect the fan, as well as between the fan itself and that plastic frame where you can see the bearing assembly and the motor.

Here's a picture of the fan after disassembly:

[image: Disassembled fan]

You pull that apart and there's a decent chance you're not getting it put back together. In either case, you'll need to remove the cooler from the CPU / motherboard entirely to make sure that you don't damage any components trying to rip the cooler apart. You don't save any time or work on disassembly by only going for the fan.

There are other problems with this approach as well. Just from disassembly we've  exposed either the motor or the bearing assembly which means that dirt and dust can get in there now. You can see that you'll also be required to have some  soldering tools and skills at your disposal as well.

You can find cheap used ones on sites like craigslist and ebay for about $10 USD very easily, just get one that matches the motherboard socket / CPU generation you have in your PC.

---

TLDR: This project is not worth saving $10. Buy a replacement cooler.

---

## How to find a replacement cooler:

If you don't want to  buy a used one then you can find aftermarket low profile coolers for $15-35 USD. You don't need anything high end for normal use. Relevant metrics will be:

- "cooler height" = how tall of a cooler your case can fit, basically  distance from mobo  socket to the opposite side of the case
- "TDP" = Thermal Design Power (this basically describes thermal dissipation). Your CPU model will have this listed on the specification sheet, so will the coolers. A CPU with a TDP of 95W (watts) will require a cooler with a TDP of equal or greater value than 95W.
- "decibel level" = amount of noise generated, lower number is less noise.
- "CFM" = Cubic feet per minute of  airflow. This is a useful objective measurement you can  use to compare fan performance against other fans. Higher CFM = more air being moved.

If a cooler doesn't list these specifications anywhere (check multiple sellers and the manufacturer site) then it is not worth purchasing.

You will also need some thermal paste to install the new (or used) cooler. I recommend Arctic Silver 5 for reliable performance and longevity at a good price. There are better pastes out there in terms of thermal conductivity but they tend to dry out faster on average than Arctic Silver.

Answer (score 0):

I checked eBay and it looks like the whole fan and heat sink is sold as one piece, whether it's a used Intel heat sink & fan or another brand. Since it's not on eBay, it's unlikely that a replacement fan only is available at any reasonable price new from Intel, if at all. If you type "replacement Intel fan" in some listings that are probably suitable do show up.

If you want to keep the heat sink, One thing you can sometimes do is get a smaller fan with holes in the 4 corners and use wood screws to screw it in between the fins of the original heat sink. The cooling and / or noise may not be as good, but if it's a lower TDP CPU it will likely be good enough. Another way that often works is using zip ties to attach a non standard fan.

edit: If you're going to down vote my answer at least say why. There does not seem to be any replacement fans available that are new. There are a couple of used ones for sale on line but that's not a reliable solution.

Comment: Downvoter, any explaination? i dont see anything wrong with this answer